# TFS - Checkout restoring original modification dates on files?

Tags: tfs

I have used many version control systems and most of them restore the file's date/time on checkout.   This is not the date/time it is checked out, or checked in, but the date on the actual file.  TFS uses the date the file was checked out.
So, I'm trying to find out what is in production.  The date of the file is 10/3/2014.   I have an 8/3/14 check-in, and an 12/3/2014 check in, and 49 check-ins following that.   The 8/3 does not match what is in production, clearly changes were made after that.  So, I want to get the latest version of each file that was before 10/3/14 on it's modification time (check in date is as always, useless)

Now, in a "normal" company, there would be a version label applied when it was built and pushed to production - but we are working with off shore (India) developers who don't do that sort of thing.   It appears that most of the 49 changes didn't make it to production, and will be rolled back.

I ended up taking file by file and trying to get something that built, and seemed to match what was in Production as best I could - and spent days putting the project back together.  (It seems developers copied files between them instead of putting them into TFS - so different people checked in different pieces of the puzzle - many versions didn't even build.)

In any event, I didn't see any way to query by real modification date.  I get how pulling files down with the correct modification dates would result in a requirement of a build-all, or deleting the object file result of that source file (in order to force a build) - but it sure would be nice to be able to get files changed since a specific date/time.

Comment: It sounds like your fundamental problem is that the code deployed to Prod has no bearing at all on what's been checked into version control.  No VCS can help you with that.  You need to fire the developers who did this, piece your project back together the best you can (which may not necessarily match Prod), and then go get a stiff drink.  Not necessarily in that order.

Comment: True, Gotta love the India developers.   Still, it would sure make my life easier if I knew when things were changed.   There are some things that the date/time on a file is an important aspect and needs to be preserved.  I really miss that ability.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly, you can query history of projects with commandline tf history with version option set to your interesting date. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx